# How to edit a specific row in KivyMD MDDataTable

Tags: kivy, material-design, kivy-language

I've poured over the source code and the documentation and can't find anything close to what I need, is there a way to edit a column and refresh the data table programmatically? I want to have a status update in the MDDatatTable

Comment: You will have to edit the `column_data` and/or `row_data`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson alright but is there a way to edit specific rows and is there a way to refresh the data or if a new item is added to my list that I'm loading will it do it automatically?

Comment: If you use the `on_row_press` event, you can get a reference to a `CellRow` instance (which is the `viewclass` for the table) and change its `text` directly. Otherwise, I think you will have to `dismiss` the `MDDataTable`, recreate it with the edited data, and `open` the new `MDDataTable`. Since this is a `RecycleView` underneath, it seems like you ought to be able to do a `refresh_from_data()`, but I could not figure out how to make that work.

Comment: @JohnAnderson alright I got all that working to where it's not a super big deal to reload it but is there anyway you can think of to get cell references to edit the text without reloading? If not I can just reload it a couple times but that's such a

Comment: @JohnAndersonactually never mind, you actually can't open the table more than once for some reason even if you dismiss it first

Comment: You can't open the table a second time because it is a `ModalView`, which has that limitation. I also should have mentioned that changing the `text` of a `CellRow` is not useful, since it is the `viewclass` of a `RecycleView` and will get recycled (losing the change).